# catkin_ws/ vs share/

Tags: ros, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone plaease explain to me what the difference between folders catkin_ws/ and /opt/ros/hydro/share is? what is the purpose of each?
thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196283/catkin_ws/-vs-share//) by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2014-10-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin_ws (could be called anything you want really, foo_ws) is the workspace in which you want to develop your packages on. Inside the catkin_ws folder in the devel/ folder you will see a setup.bash file. If you source this bash file, it will mean that your current terminal window is set up to the environment of your catkin_ws.

opt/ros/hydro/share is where all the debian packages you download from sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-*whatever package* will be installed to. Inside that folder is just the binary executables, and you most likely won't see any source files in there, except maybe for some include files. As a good practice, You don't want to edit things in this folder because this is where pre-approved, tested, and working ros packages go. If you want to possibly modify some code (say for a pull request) for some package, you should rather download the source for that package from github or wherever, *put it into your catkin_ws* and then build it inside your catkin_ws. So to sum things up, put the code you will write/modify, into your catkin_ws. apt-get installed ros packages into the /opt/ros/[distro]/share folder.

Hope this clarifies some things

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on 2014-10-30**:
Thank you so much!!

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2019-03-12**:
The `/opt/ros/kinetic/share` folder of ros kinetic only includes the cmake modules, and the executables you mentioned are stored in the `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib` directory.

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-02-21**:
Hi there, thanks for explaining the above.
From my understanding:

1. I can create a launch file to call unmodified packages I need from `/opt/ros/distro/share`.
2. I can also create launch file and call modified packages installed in `catkin_ws`.

Question is, can they both work together?
Thank you.